# express.js application authenticating to multiple apis

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, active-directory, jira

I am trying to create an application with the following requirements.

1. Login page for entire application that authenticates against AD
   (currently using `passport-activedirectory`)
2. This also needs to authenticate against a `jira` api for the user to create tickets through my application. Should this be done at
   initial auth or once the route is hit to send the request to `jira`?
3. It's possible that other api's will need to be authenticated against.

I'm trying to figure out the best way/standard way to do this so the user will only have to authenticate through my web application once.

Any direction is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: So typically passport is a "we support this many auth services and you can auth against one" not a "we will auth you against x number of services". It sounds to me like you need to authenticate the user with active directory to "auth against your app" and then you need to authenticate against Jira and other services on the back-end, probably not directly related to passport.

Comment: @chev - Exactly.  The user will auth directly against my app with their ad credentials (this is also the same credentials that are used for jira).  The main question is how do I store the username/password so that in the event a ticket needs to be created in jira I have the information and can just pass that to the jira api and create a ticket using the username and password they authenticated with?

Comment: I haven't messed with the Jira API in ages but you should be able to get an auth token for your app to authenticate with Jira without having to know your users' usernames or passwords.